# MIcrosoft Dynamics CRM - Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, dynamics-crm

This is biggest part of error message (I had to remove part from Detailed Compiler Output):

> Server Error in '/' Application. Compilation Error Description: An
>   error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0008: Unexpected error reading metadata from
>   file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary
>   ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\dc9dbdc3\00d95cf7_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Common.Application.Pages.DLL'
>   -- 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. '
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File:    Line: 0
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> c:\windows\system32\inetsrv>
>   "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe" /t:library
>   /utf8output
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\997f5f6f\0013306c_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Service.Entities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\156d605f\b04ec721_34d5d001\AntiXssLibrary.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\babe0969\00adb7aa_e28fd101\Microsoft.Azure.Common.NetFramework.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\166b4ffd\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Rollup.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7541bffe\00f6555c_80b7d201\Microsoft.Crm.GeoTimeZone.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\c6dd29d3\009ac36f_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Common.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\6b029753\008abef9_d901d101\Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\e32cb015\00b9cd69_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtension.Common.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\2d64d539\005a7823_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.WebServices.SystemCustomization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\cf18f4f2\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sales.Entities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\b9f4b0d1\00d8d763_02e6d401\Microsoft.Dynamics.Telemetry.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\0f255e29\005841cb_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Admin.AdminService.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7a82051b\002240c4_5d01d301\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\318f20d3\009b1110_ef8fd101\Microsoft.OData.Edm.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\2176cd32\004f0d08_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Admin.DMSnapinLib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\9e0d1518\000c06d0_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.WebServices.Workflow.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\775de9e2\00d8d763_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Platform.BusinessProcess.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\aa2cb5c6\00f50ec3_5d01d301\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\abd11bdb\006ee00e_ef8fd101\Microsoft.OData.Client.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\15f37248\808b3826_34d5d001\Microsoft.ServiceBus.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\743208ad\003937d1_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ReportingServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7e2bca8f\00e6fe6a_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.MetadataService.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\135ebf0d\0033bff9_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Sdk.FormControls.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\a92f8352\006e1702_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Server.Utility.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\4f2cce37\40beef21_34d5d001\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\c98444fb\00215773_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\28ccde2f\008f0513_e18fd101\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\5980ec3c\003937d1_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\ddad85fd\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sales.Application.Platform.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\0e933bfc\000c06d0_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Common.Application.WebServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\44c7164c\00f866f1_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.CrmLive.MicrosoftOnline.Client.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\ca5dfb22\0013306c_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Service.ObjectModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7208be46\00e82e55_80b7d201\Microsoft.Crm.RelationshipIntelligence.Request.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\451a3e7b\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Marketing.Entities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\90249bdf\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sales.Application.Pages.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\34f84da9\00f50ec3_5d01d301\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\a8c66aa9\a08b3b0d_7dbed001\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\9bdf2fe7\0013306c_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Database.Common.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\60579ee1\00f50ec3_5d01d301\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\06a6dd1f\00c7f470_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ExchangeProxy.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activation\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activation.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\22504f19\004f0d08_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Common.ImportExportPublish.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\55708a22\00c7f470_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Scheduling.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\5ce730b1\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Tools.EDW.Framework.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\ede64618\00215773_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Tools.Logging.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\a43f53d4\003937d1_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Common.ObjectModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\dc9dbdc3\00d95cf7_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Common.Application.Pages.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\34c43de0\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.WebServices.AdvancedFind.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\4e20da48\0013306c_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ServiceBus.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\f7303b64\0079821d_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.WebServices.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\dcc3c9bc\008ef983_81b7d201\MicrosoftCrmOnlineCloudSharedEvents.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\3327a2f8\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Authentication.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\87908d0b\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ExternalIntegration.AzureTextAnalytics.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\d982af5c\008d21fc_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\366b98ad\00de4f3b_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.DiscoveryService.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\e7b7690f\00872ea6_a823d101\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\b1103b58\00e82e55_80b7d201\Microsoft.Crm.RelationshipIntelligence.UCISClient.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\b13e0dc2\00c0ef39_79b0d101\Microsoft.Crm.Online.Tps.TpsServiceClient.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\f6e96de1\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.Components.WebServices.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\088c2f4a\00adb7aa_e28fd101\Microsoft.Azure.Common.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\34301a22\00e6fe6a_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Sdk.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7469c2dc\008f0513_e18fd101\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\5b432c97\003da581_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ProvisioningPublishing.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\cfee25e4\00050965_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Monitoring.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\c392aa41\804877a0_64bbd001\DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\90bf74dc\002f7e7a_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Yammer.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\4b04a59b\00db934f_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.Interop.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\5fac7d53\00d23648_0f27d101\Microsoft.Crm.Online.Cloud.CloudSyncApiModels.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\ee9acdc4\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Application.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\41e3bfd2\001a2dd7_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Unzip.Common.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\d6bf28a5\0014b5ff_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Platform.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\3891b807\008f0513_e18fd101\Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\951bd42c\00e6fe6a_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtension.Common.Fetch.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\e23b0900\00514460_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Utilities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\cedd73e9\00e6fe6a_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Marketing.Application.WebServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\9dddd73f\005f6b67_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Setup.DatabaseInstaller.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\700ab31d\000c06d0_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sales.Application.WebServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\552ee3b1\00f866f1_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Service.Application.Components.Application.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\0a4b5aff\00d51b78_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ApplicationBuildUpgrade.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\71fc1efc\00050965_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ObjectModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\9adfd7dd\004f0d08_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Platform.Server.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\b93fb391\00d95cf7_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.DeploymentService.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\2d155ed8\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.CalculatedField.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\b4bc1d34\00834bc2_a824d201\Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\f52c45b9\0060f0fa_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ServiceControl.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\24c6b40e\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.UI.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\feda3832\00d95cf7_01e6d401\CDOSYS.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\989fd2f7\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.DuplicateDetection.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\d5f855cc\0021dcf4_a823d101\Microsoft.Data.Services.Client.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\6ef8a583\0052c9f3_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Service.Application.Pages.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\e0d2d18c\00215773_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Setup.DiffBuilder.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\0c9066cb\00050965_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Setup.Shared.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\19e34e45\001a2dd7_01e6d401\ADODB.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\8160543a\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\f34b861d\00d95cf7_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Service.Application.Components.Platform.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\343c8cf7\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Reserved.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\d0071536\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ExternalIntegration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7cb457e9\00323a66_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\64bcf0e4\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ExternalIntegration.AzureRecommendations.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\17074378\009dee64_42d6d101\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\adcdb3c7\003937d1_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Marketing.ObjectModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\459194a2\006d926e_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.WebServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\b921143b\00e6fe6a_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sales.ObjectModel.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7d59cb07\00ba52fd_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Shared.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\efd00e8c\007c3e09_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Common.Application.Platform.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\a445197e\009dee64_42d6d101\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\fb7f8085\008d21fc_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Core.Extensions.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\3f82bbf1\0022dc06_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Reporting.DataExtensionShim.CrmReportingInterfaces.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7ba6bd1f\00d51b78_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.MetadataHelper.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\f338059d\90cd081d_7dbed001\System.Web.Http.Cors.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\33dcf21b\00323a66_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.XmlSerializers.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\cb777d3f\00d1b4e8_e28fd101\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\e7a061f7\003b6e29_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Mobile.Application.Pages.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\07baab70\0024135f_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.ProvisioningQueue.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\aa5d19d3\f07e5e06_7dbed001\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\7040965a\00d8d763_02e6d401\Microsoft.CRM.Authentication.S2S.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\713d03cf\003a6e17_a923d101\System.Spatial.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\8b8c6960\20098e08_7dbed001\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\e0160011\00bbdeb1_e28fd101\Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\ccb5f377\0014b5ff_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Common.Entities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\3386c965\00323a66_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Core.WebServices.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\0301b72f\90dfa56d_e0c4d001\Microsoft.Crm.Asynchronous.Workflow.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\778073d1\009b1110_ef8fd101\Microsoft.OData.Core.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\db045bab\00e6fe6a_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.Client.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\4f720b3d\0040616d_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.VisualizationModules.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\8f9a1e88\0013306c_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.SafeHtml.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\b3325bf0\00adb7aa_e28fd101\Hyak.Common.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\a675cd66\00475ed8_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Strings.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\3776cbe7\008abef9_d901d101\Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Activities\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Activities.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\56e6255c\00edfbd5_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.Converters.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\59a241a8\00e6fe6a_02e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Marketing.Application.Platform.dll"
>   /R:"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET

Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.8.3761.0

for C# 5
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

This compiler is provided as part of the Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, but only supports language versions up to C# 5, which is no longer the latest version. For compilers that support newer versions of the C# programming language, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533240

fatal error CS0008: Unexpected error reading metadata from file 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\8dfc503f\901eed87\assembly\dl3\dc9dbdc3\00d95cf7_01e6d401\Microsoft.Crm.Common.Application.Pages.DLL' -- 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. '

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4075.0

Comment: So, how much storage space is left on your CRM and/or SQL server?  Seems not enough.

Comment: CRM and SQL Server are on same machine, I have more then 50GB of disk space free and server is using between 50-60% of 16GB RAM, It was working before server crashed few days ago. MSCRM_CONFIG.mdf was damaged but it is restored now, error message did not change , There was one more thing damaged Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Shell (Isolated), but it was reinstalled.

Comment: Do you have autogrowth set for your db files?  Are they full?

Comment: yes I have automatic growth and size for database and log files are unlimited